# How do I install Windows 8 on Wine?

Tags: wine, windows-8

Clearly no one has tried to do this but I don't have a windows 8 disc. I do however have a product key and that's all I need. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I've installed the .exe file to download windows 8. I've installed wine and tried many things with wine thing and nothing is working. I need someone to tell me. step by step. how to do this so I can run windows 8 or maybe even 7 again and go on with my life.

Comment: If you dont want Ubuntu, Get a windows 8 dvd and clean install . Simple. If you want both, install windows in a separate partition and run ubuntu from live cd to get grub. Lots of links on this forum and on the web for both.

Comment: Despite the initial tone the question is useful to other users who think that this a possible way to download and install Windows through Ubuntu. You also can't blame Microsoft or computer manufacturers for not clearly enough telling users that you really need to run these programs from an actual Windows installation to complete successfully.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean WUBI perhaps? Wine is -NOT- something you install Windows in. Wine is used to mimic the Windows registry and dll's (yeah I know, it is the very short version) so you can use Windows **software**. That is not Windows itself.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

You need installation or recovery media of the Windows version you want to install.

Possible solutions:

- [Obtain Windows 8.1 Update 1 installation media - I have Windows 8 Keys](https://superuser.com/q/788341/252532)
- Call the customer support hotline from the computer manufacturer or buy a download from Microsoft.

---

### Windows Upgrade Assistant and similar programs on Wine

If you are talking about the [Upgrade Assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-7-tutorial) it's very unlikely that this program will function under Wine as originally designed by Microsoft when running on Windows.

This is neither Microsoft's nor Wine's fault.

If this program actually completes successfully you would end up with all of the contents it tries to download and install in your Wine environment, because that is what this program seems to be designed to do:

- Update the existing Windows environment to a newer version.
- In case of Wine being the existing environment or *"Windows partition"*, this would be `~/.wine/drive_c` or `~/.wine64/drive_c` respectively.
- Even if you check the to option to do a `clean install` and `not keep existing data`, this program will still use the same partition and likely the same filesystem.

I ran this program on my machine to update my initial Windows 7 installation to Windows 8 and in retrospect found the program behaving like above, where it actually should have created a new GPT partition table or converted the existing MBR partition table to GPT to be identical to preinstalled Windows 8 installations. But this would introduce a lot more of difficulties, dependencies and possible sources for failures. Also converting UEFI capable legacy machines to actual UEFI machines through such an application would be questionable and prompting the average user to confirm such an action also be very confusing.

**Conclusion:** You need installation or recovery media of the Windows version you want to install.

If your computer shipped to you in a pristine condition with a recovery partition and you wiped everything without backing up, you now know that backups are useful. ***Kindly*** ask the support hotline for help.

Note: You can convert Windows 8 MBR installations to Windows 8 GPT by using [DISM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825079.aspx) to backup (and restore), convert or create a GPT table, restore and run [bcdboot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824874.aspx). That is another topic though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what specific executable you are using, different wine settings are needed. Take a look if your application can be found at https://appdb.winehq.org/ for more information.

I've been able to use the Dreamspark downloader in the past using playonlinux:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to proceed in a different direction than those who answered before me.  I am going to assume, possibly incorrectly, that you are new to Wine and what you believe you are actually trying to do is to install a full working installation of Windows 8 as a Virtual Machine under Ubuntu, and you had been misled to believe Wine does that.

As far as I know, and I'm pretty handy with WINE, Wine does not permit the installation of the complete Windows installation within itself.  I don't believe that's what it was designed to do.  Wine can emulate many versions of Windows, Including Windows 7, in order to permit you to run software made to run best under those versions.

**If you wish to run a program such as *MS-Word*, using Wine, that's especially easy:**

1. Go to the Ubuntu Software Center and, if you have already installed
   WINE, find it and uninstall WINE.
2. Install WINETRICKS. (winetricks installs more essential packages for
   running windows software than you'll otherwise discover)
3. Install PlayOnLinux.  (PlayOnLinux helps you to painlessly install
   your old Windows applications such as Quicken, MS-office). 
   Installing Picasa under wine is a bigger ordeal but it is possible,
   and I've done it.
4. Open PlayOnLinux.
5. Click on the Install icon.

The reason for installing PlayOnLinux is that it has installation helpers which will permit you to install MS Word without difficulties.

If on the other hand you actually want to run an entire Windows Installation under Ubuntu, you can do that.  It requires going to the Ubuntu Software Center and searching for "Virtualbox", which is a VMware manager.  It was a lot easier to use than I thought it would be, but it was a real headache with regard to giving Windows access to Internet or CD drives.  For a friend hell-bent on using both Ubuntu and also running a particular windows game which was too finicky to work with WINE, such an installation was apparently necessary.